# Node.js: AWS SES sendRawEmail: mails not getting sent to BCC addresses

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am sending a mail with attachments using [mailcomposer](https://github.com/nodemailer/mailcomposer) and the `sendRawEmail` method of the AWS SDK. I am able to send the emails using the `to` and `cc` fields but when I add an address in `bcc`, the mail does not get delivered. There is no failure though. Is there any extra configuration not mentioned in the docs that I might be missing ?

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer in [one of the issues](https://github.com/nodemailer/mailcomposer/issues/65) of mailcomposer. You need to add one extra config in the mail options.

```
var mail = mailcomposer(options);
mail.keepBcc = true;
```

Comment: Thanks! Since they moved this entire thing into nodemailer, the link to your issue does no longer exist, and they also removed all the issues in their github repository

Comment: Now you need to use `var mail = new MailComposer({}).compile()`. keepBcc is still needed and undocumented.